# Measurement in QM as an approximate form of unitary evolution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

It is tempting to describe the wave function collapse / the measurement procedure as an approximate form of unitary evolution of a composite system consisting of a simple subsystem (being measured) and a much more complex system (the observer). Here "simple" and "much more complex" refer to significantly differing Hilbert space dimensions.

I am looking for the relevant / recent / accessible materials on this subject.

To be more precise: I am interested in toy models, in which the unitary evolution of the composite system looks effectively as a projective measurement of a subsystem.

Comment: There's an entire book about this called _Decoherence and the Quantum-to-Classical Transition_ by Schlosshauer.

Comment: I guess, the answer to my question is given in Section 2.10 of this book.

Comment: If you have found an answer, please consider answering the question with your own answer so that other people can learn from it!

Comment: What is "approximately unitary" about this?

Comment: Well, a projective measurement cannot be formally represented as unitary evolution. But I think under certain conditions unitary evolution may look similar to projective measurements.